# Improving a Jasmine spec to test properties of arguments to calls

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, jasmine

I'm using the following Coffeescript code to validate that initialization of one backbone.js view constructs another:

```
describe 'Avia.AviaView', ->

  beforeEach ->
    @aviaView = new Avia.AviaView(addFixtureDiv('avia'))
    @matricesView = new Backbone.View()

    spyOn(Avia, 'MatricesView').andCallFake(
      (element) =>
        if !element
          throw "Expected MatricesView to be constructed with a parent element"
        else if element.attr('id') != 'tabs-3'
          throw "Expected MatricesView to be constructed with the parent element #tabs-3"
        else
          @matricesView
    )

  describe 'initialize', ->

    beforeEach ->
      @aviaView.initialize()

    it 'creates a new MatricesView ', ->
      expect(Avia.MatricesView).toHaveBeenCalledOnce()
```

This works nicely, but I can't help but think it ought to be possible to improve it.  I'm imagining a syntax like:

```
it 'creates a new MatricesView ', ->
  expect(Avia.MatricesView).toHaveBeenCalledMatching((args...) => args[0].attr('id') == 'tabs-3')
```

... where `toHaveBeenCalledMatching` takes a function that takes a splat of the arguments, and returns truthy to indicate success, and falsy otherwise.

Has anyone come across something like this, or do I need to roll my own here?  Or, has anyone a better suggestion of how to improve this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [toHaveBeenCalledWith()](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/jsdoc/symbols/jasmine.Matchers.html#toHaveBeenCalledWith) not work for you? In most cases you either know the values ahead of time, or can calculate them.

If you really need to use a function to evaluate the args for the call, you could use separate expectations and [argsForCall](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/jsdoc/symbols/jasmine.Spy.html#argsForCall) to test each arg individually.

If worst comes to worst, you can always write your own matcher. But that sounds a lot harder than the first two :)